# DataContractJsonSerializer not available

Tags: c#, .net, json, visual-studio-2017

**Environment**: Visual Studio 2017 on a Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (1709)

**Goal**: Serialize a JSON Object using DataContractJsonSerializer

**Problem**: I am unable to resolve DataContractJsonSerializer. Looking at y project References I tried adding System.Runtime.Serializtion (v4.0.30319) to my references but no luck. Is there an additional reference/package needed to access DataContractJsonSerializer.

**Alternative** : Yes, I am aware that I could use NewtonSoft.Json and probably will but wanted a conclusive answer before adding an additional dependency to my project.

**Research**: I tried looking to SO as well as on Google and DataContractJsonSerializer is still highly referenced and could not find something that was atleast obvious to me on what might be going wrong.

**Project File**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{53E26A85-0C38-4B64-9C45-7FF41EBF22F5}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>ConsoleApp1</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>ConsoleApp1</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.Serialization" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

**Output** :

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApp1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>C:\Users\amarne\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs(24,13,24,39): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DataContractJsonSerializer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
1>C:\Users\amarne\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs(24,50,24,76): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DataContractJsonSerializer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Share your project file.

Comment: Just added the project into the question

Comment: I took your project file, dumped App.config and AssemblyInfo.cs, and I can compile against `DataContractJsonSerializer` just fine with VS2017 v15.4.2 on Windows 10 v1709. Can you share your exact compiler/msbuild output?

Comment: Hmm Weird.. updating question with error

Comment: I assume you definitely have `using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;` at the top of your source file? [This](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwD4AEAMACFBGA3AWACh0tsA6AJQFcA7GASzDjIGVF6IAbegLwgYD2NMgCkoQgoSI0ITKAAcIAYzgYAwkPGc4AQXnzsRAN5EAkCgBMpAOxmThU+YDMpAGxYALKQAcAChxoANoAuhgQCADmUACUZqb2jqYAbuFhGAC8GDRwAO4YACL8EBp0CMowYkJsCBzcPIi+MACe8nACAGb+2GjR0ZKJOACcvhBkAOJwMAAqLXC+0WQAYlScnABysnB9cQC+ZnuEO0A=) compiles fine for me with your project.

Comment: NVM so this is kind of embarrassing. When i first tried this i hadn't added System.Runtime.Serialization by explicitly going to Add a Reference and checking the box. When i don't add that while i have the ability to resolve upto System.Runtime.Serialization but after that only have .formatters. Then at some point i added the reference but when i checked again i guess the resolver was still catching up. Now when i tried again i was able to add the reference and everything worked. Sigh.. Sorry for randomizing you i guess :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well thanx to Yaakov I figured out what happened. 
For those using DataContractJsonSerializer for the first time remember to manually add the reference to **System.Runtime.Serialization** once you do that 
you should be able to resolve "using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;"

In my case i guess when after adding the reference i just saw that VS wasn't happy and then did not manually build it. So i was on the right track just didn't give it enough time :)